# Can rain damage a device so it drains more power?

Tags: batteries

I have a Kindle e-book reader. It got wet while camping in a rain by my stupidity. After the rain, it would not turn on and would not even charge from a powerbank, but it picked up after I left it in a wall adapter overnight twice. However, the capacity of the battery was much less (I would say it went from 3-4 books to one book worth of reading). I bought a new battery. However, the new battery gets depleted as fast as the old one.

Can it be because of the rain? I would assume water would make the device unusable, or would damage the battery, but is it plausibly possible it somehow made the device drain more energy? Another option is that my (non-Amazon) battery is really bad, but I find it suspicious that the capcity seems to be about hte same as the old battery.

Comment: You can get corrosion anywhere on the circuit board, leading to a short pretty much anywhere, that draws current. You can also get damage on components that are just there to protect the rest of the electronics, but aren't crucial for the board to function, commonly TVS diodes or reverse polarity protection componets etc. These can get short-circuit behavior when they break, so they just sit there and draw loads of current while the product is otherwise still working fine.

Comment: And these would not be visible on the motherboard with a naked eye, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, anything can happen.

Even pure water is somewhat conductive and low power devices like an E-reader rely on the internal signal being **completely isolated** from one another. Even a small amount of water can compromise this isolation and then anything can happen. Without the proper isolation, currents can "leak" and that can drain a battery.

Also water in combination with the voltages that are constantly present in the device (since it has a battery) causes **corrosion** so contacts break and unwanted paths for currents to flow can form.

> I would assume water would make the device unusable
>   That depends on the amount of water and how long it is present in the device.

My guess is that there is still some water left in the E-reader. You could try putting the E-reader in a closed container with uncooked rice. Rice attracts water. This is a fairly safe method to try.

Less safe is putting it in an oven at low temperature (60 Celcius or lower) for a couple of hours. You have to trust the oven though, that it will **NOT** heat above 60 C I mean.

Edit: Pro tip: remove the battery before doing any of this!

Comment: ahhh, oven, potentially pre-damaged lithium battery... I don't know.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I would just remove the battery before doing the rice or oven procedure ;-)

Comment: Hm, can there still be water if it is about four months since this happened? Will try the rice thing though!